# Multiplying columns of matrix by a unit quaternion

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that we have $X\in SO(3)$ and we embed it in $SO(4)$ by putting it in the bottom right of  a $4\times 4$ matrix $Y$ with $0$'s in the first row and column except the top left entry, which equals $1$.

> Let $x\in S^3$, the unit quaternions. If we right-multiply each column
>   of  $Y$ by $x$ (i.e., for column vector $v$ we take $vx$ as the new vector in that column), will the resulting matrix still be in $SO(4)$?

Right-multiplying preserves orthonormality, but I need to see what it does to the determinant.

My idea is to use some type of matrix representation with respect to the quaternion basis $(1,i,j,k)$ in order to see whether the determinant will still be $1$ after multiplying.

But I'm not sure how this would work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking what $\det(YA)$ is, with $A=(x,x,x,x)$? If yes, my advice would be to compute $\det(A)$ first.

Comment: @andre I see, but wouldn't $YA$ give left-multiplication? Also, wouldn't that $A$ have zero determinant?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, what you called  "right-multiply each column of Y by x", could you please define this with a formula? I thought you simply mixed up columns and rows.

Comment: @andre Just did.

Comment: What are the components of the new vector $vx$, i.e. $(vx)_{k}$ with $k=1,\ldots,4$? I still believe you will get somehow a zero determinant.

Comment: @andre It's just the product of two quaternions.

Comment: I would rewrite everything as equations with real numbers instead with quaternions and see what this would result in. Apropos, how would you define a determinant for quaternionic matrices?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing here is that "apply a linear transformation to the columns of a matrix" is the same operation as "take the product of the matrix representing the linear transformation with the given matrix". i.e.

$$ [T(v_1) \mid T(v_2) \mid \ldots \mid T(v_n) ] = [T] \; [v_1\mid v_2 \mid \ldots \mid v_n] $$

Judging from the comments you seem aware of this, but are being confused because you are using a right action of the quaternions on vectors and are getting confused by notation, so let me emphasize this point:

> Multiplying a vector on the *right* by a quaternion is a linear transformation, and thus is given by multiplying on the *left* by a matrix.

In other words, there is a matrix $\rho(x)$ such that $v \cdot x = \rho(x)  v$.

To help straighten this out, notice that a *right* action by a group is the same thing as a *left* action by its opposite group — i.e. the matrices $\rho$ satisfy $\rho(x y) = \rho(y) \rho(x)$.

If you don't want to twist the variance, you might instead define matrices  $\sigma(x) = \rho(x^{-1})$, so that $\sigma(xy) = \sigma(x) \sigma(y)$. Then, the formula for the group action would be $v \cdot x = \sigma(x^{-1}) v$.

---

Incidentally, having a group act linearly on column vectors *from the right* is generally a bad idea, because it results in lots of misleading notation, such as this very question!

In my opinion, you'll do yourself a favor if you make the necessary modifications so that you work with a left action instead.

Comment: I tried multiplying each of the four quaternion basis vectors (i.e., 1, i, j,and k) on the right by a fixed unit quaternion. I get a matrix representation with respect to this basis with real entries. I compute the determinant and after reducing the result, I see an expression that will give me exactly $1$ basis on the fact that the multiplier was a unit quaternion. This is what I want, but do you think it works?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, here is a quick way to see this. Let $1,b,c,d$ be the columns of $Y$, thought of as quaternions, and let $Y_x$ be the matrix with columns $x,bx,cx,dx$. Then

$x\wedge bx\wedge cx\wedge dx=(\det(Y_x))1\wedge i\wedge j\wedge k.$

But this implies that $\det(Y_x)=1$, because every 1-dimensional representation of the unit quaternions is trivial.

Comment: Morally speaking: the unit quaternions are connected, so where could the determinant switch from $1$ to $-1$?